# Can't boot Ubuntu from Vmware

Tags: boot, usb, mouse, vmware

I am using Vmware Workstation 11. I installed ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS (64 bit),
and have been using these for more than a month.

Normally, after power up Vmware, it only took a few seconds to boot up ubuntu.
Start from a black screen with Vmware logo, then 2 lines show up in the screen
(some bus action, and PIIx??) - this means Vmware find ubuntu.

But, yesterday, I experienced the following, and until now I can't boot ubuntu
from Vmware.

I saw the following 3 messages on Vmware -

1. After virtual machine power up, screen stays in black with Vmware logo.
   When I tried to power off Vmware, I saw "virtual machine is busy. Wait   until all the operation completed before closing". I googled, and use task manager to kill `vmware-vmx.exe`.
2. I tried to power up virtual machine again, and see "The other application
   is using the virtual machine, take ownership from it". I googled, and
   deleted .lck files under some directories.
3. Then I saw "Can't open the disk ... vmdk or one of the snapshot disk it depends on. Module disk power on failed. Again, I deleted all the .lck files I can find.
4. I tried to power up again, Vmware stays in black screen with Vmware logo.
   The 2 lines I used to see (some bus action, and pIIx?) does not shows up.
   Looks like Vmware can't find ubuntu OS.

What should I do to troubleshoot from here?

I have 2 questions:

1. Do I have to connect to internet when I boot up Ubuntu? (I don't think this
   is required, since sometimes I boot up Ubuntu without having internet connection).
2. Does the usb mouse matter? I usually use a wireless mouse (usb stick + wireless mouse), but yesterday I used a wire mouse and inserted into a different usb slot than the one I usually inserted the usb mouse.

I created a new virtual machine with Ubuntu 64 bit (which will use an .iso file to install Ubuntu), but I can't get Vmware to go to configure Ubuntu. Virtual machine seem can't find Ubuntu image and boot.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there was an update for VmWare which broke it. You can install VirtualBox, I guess, it supports same virtual hard disc. More information about migrating is [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/125640/how-to-convert-virtual-machines-between-virtualbox-and-vmware/) and Oracle official instructions are [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/fatbloke/entry/moving_a_vmware_vm_to) - since you can't boot VmWare, you will have to modify steps from official instructions.

To answer to other questions, no internet connecion is required to start Ubuntu since most devices uses wifi connection, which connects after OS boot. And no, it doesn't matter if you use another mouse in another USB.

Comment: Jirka: Vmware will be used in the current project I am working on, I have to stick on that.

Comment: Ok, then you can use VirtualBox just for test. Or if you moved virtual machine to other PC make sure that CPU supports virtualization. If everithing is same as before, then it's weird that it won't boot from iso.

Comment: I think I got some clue on this:  the virtual machine which got problem seem to have memory exceeded issue. I allocated 80GB to that virtual machine, while I built several large image recently, memory is probably exceeded the limit. (I looked at the folder for that virtual machine, it's 76 GB, however, during run time, some temp file may make this go beyard this.).